# How do I set up an entityreference entity base field to show as a link to the target entity?

Tags: entities, 8

I have a base field on my entity type that's an entity reference, e.g.:

```
    $fields['type'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
```

How do I set this up so it displays as a link to the target?

Answer (score 0):

```
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
        'label' => 'above',
        'type' => 'entity_reference_label',
        'settings' => [
          'link' => TRUE,
        ],
      ])
```

and optionally to allow it to be configured in the UI:

```
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE)
```